# Pulling data from 332 .csv files and returning the number of observed cases for each variable in the file

Tags: r, csv

I am writing an R function that reads a directory full of 332 .csv files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function returns a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases. For example:

```
ID  OBS
1   233
2   149
etc.
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(files_full[id]))
    data <- data.frame(id, nobs)
    return(data)
```

}

The problem here is that, while  the function does run, it gives me a value of 1 for each "nobs" in my column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit different approach:

```
complete <- function(directory, pattern = "csv$") {
    setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(
            rbind,
            lapply(
                list.files(directory, pattern = pattern, full.names=TRUE),
                function(fname) list(fname, sum(complete.cases(read.csv(fname))))
            )
   )), c("file", "complete"))
}
```

If you want to keep `id` as an argument:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    count_complete <- function(fname) sum(complete.cases(read.csv(fname)))
    fnames <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)[id]
    data.frame(id = id, complete = unlist(lapply(fnames, count_complete)))
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it while keeping the initial "function(directory, id = 1:332)" the same?

Comment: I wonder if someone will suggest a `lf %>% read.csv %>% complete.cases %>% sum %>% setNames` alternative

Comment: @Daniel it's not entirely clear what you really aim to do with id=1:332 (select only the first 332 files? but what if you accidentally have other files in the list? wouldn't it be better to `grep()` for specific filenames after list.files?)

Comment: @baptiste thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I've updated the code, having edited the "dat["ID"] to just "id". The fx seems to be working about half correctly: it prints the correct ID for each csv file in a neat little list, but it does **not** show the correct number of non-NA observations for each file. How should I edit my code to fix this?

Comment: @zero323 thank you very much! This function works, but I was wondering if there was a way to not show the file and file name in the data frame? I'd like to show a simpler list.

Comment: @Daniel `sum(complete.cases(files_full[i]))` makes no sense: it's summing the number of complete cases in a character vector of length one (the current filename). You probably want `sum(complete.cases(dat))`, though it's entirely unclear (and very inefficient in any case) why you grow (rbind) `dat` and not `data` at every step. Either of the proposed solutions would be better IMO.

Comment: @baptiste thanks for your help. Admittedly, I'm new to learning R so I can understand why some of my code doesn't make much sense. Conceptually, I'm trying to build a data frame and then "pull" two of the columns into a new data frame. I know this isn't terribly efficient but I plan on working on tighter coding once I get some of the basics down. Anyway, I changed the code to sum(complete.cases(dat)) and I still have the same problem: while everything else looks correct for the returned data frame, it isn't tallying up the number of complete data points in the column for each .csv file.

Answer (score 3):

`sum(complete.cases(files_full[i]))` doesn't make much sense, it's probably where you went wrong.

I'd do it like this,

1- define a function to treat a single dataset,

```
read_and_summarise <- function(f, ...) {d <- read.csv(f, ...) ; sum(complete.cases(d))}
```

2- apply this function to all files,

```
lf <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
vapply(lf, read_and_summarise, 0L)
```

(untested)

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through what your code is actually doing:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    # list files
    files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    # create an empty placeholder, to grow sequentially. Known in some circles as R Inferno 
    # http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/
    dat <- data.frame()
    for (i in id) { # select filenames based on their position in the list 
                    # (prone to errors, because it depends on the order)
            dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_full[i])) # read the data, and append it 
                                                       # to previous data.frame. Why??
            nobs <- sum(complete.cases(files_full[i])) # number of complete cases...
                                                       # in a character vector of length 1
            data <- data.frame(id, nobs)               # this gets overwritten every time
    }
    data
}
```

Below's what you probably meant to write:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    # list files
    files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    files_toread <- files_full[id] # filter out unwanted files (tip: ?grep is better)
    output <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = 0)
    for (i in id) { 
            tmp <- read.csv(files_toread[i]) # read the data
            nobs <- sum(complete.cases(tmp)) # number of complete cases
            output[i, "nobs"] <- nobs
    }
    output
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @baptiste! Yes, I do see that I don't need to rbind the file. Having removed it, I have the following code (updated in the OP). How would you go about amending this code to get the desired result? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by files_full being a character vector of length 1, how do I change it to seek out each individual CSV and pull the complete cases for each column in that file?

Answer (score 2):

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  x = list.files(directory)
  y = x[match(id, as.numeric(sub(".csv","",x)))]
  z = file.path(directory, y)
  a = function(z) sum(complete.cases(read.csv(z)))
  data.frame(id = id, nobs = unlist(lapply(z,a)))
}

complete("specdata",4:14)
```

Edit:
This code matches id with file name, instead of subsetting all files by number id. A nested function is created to read and analyze files. In the data.frame, the new function is list applied to the vector of matched file paths, within an unlist() to return only the number of complete cases.

Comment: Please describe your solution in more elaborate way.

Comment: 1. create list of files in directory. 2. create list of file numbers and format as numeric. 3. select file from list of files matching ID argument with number list. 4. create file path for selected files. 5. create function to sum complete records in selected file. 5. create data frame with id as column1 and column2 as result of previous sum function applied to selected file.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution which seems easier to read:

```
complete <- function(directory,id=1:332){
    filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
    filePaths <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")
    nFiles=length(id)
    output <- matrix(ncol=2, nrow=nFiles)
    for(i in 1:nFiles){
        output[i,]= c(id[i],sum(complete.cases(read.csv(filePaths[i]))))
    }
    output <- setNames(data.frame(output),c("id","nobs"))
    output
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler and more easy to understand:

```
    complete <- function(dir, id = 1:332){

    dir <- list.files(dir, full.names = T)
    count <- data.frame()

    for(i in id){
            ok <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(dir[i])))
            count <- rbind(count, ok)
    }
    count_table <- cbind(id, count)
    colnames(count_table) <- c("id", "nobs")
    count_table
    }
```